# Apparent bug with Facebook Graph API with some combinations of like.limit and posts limit when requesting News Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get an HTTP 500 response with a return JSON of -
 {"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"} 
when I make a Graph API request for News Feed posts using the following URL:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,to,to.name,to.picture,from,from.picture,from.name,message,link,type,status_type,story,picture,description,created_time,updated_time,actions,likes.summary(true).limit(1000),comments.summary(true)&date_format=U&access_token=<token>&limit=50](https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,to,to.name,to.picture,from,from.picture,from.name,message,link,type,status_type,story,picture,description,created_time,updated_time,actions,likes.summary%28true%29.limit%281000%29,comments.summary%28true%29&date_format=U&access_token=<token>&limit=50)

I find that if I reduce the number of "like limits" to 300 that I get a successful return with news feed information. Example of successful request:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,to,to.name,to.picture,from,from.picture,from.name,message,link,type,status_type,story,picture,description,created_time,updated_time,actions,likes.summary(true).limit(300),comments.summary(true)&date_format=U&access_token=<token>&limit=50](https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,to,to.name,to.picture,from,from.picture,from.name,message,link,type,status_type,story,picture,description,created_time,updated_time,actions,likes.summary%28true%29.limit%28300%29,comments.summary%28true%29&date_format=U&access_token=<token>&limit=50)

I tried other combinations of the limit for "likes" and the limit for news feed posts (the last "&limit=DD" in the arg string) and found that I could pass a likes limit of 1000 with a smaller post limit of, say, 10 or 15, with success.

Does anyone know if/what the "limits on limits" are in this context? I suspect this may just be a Graph API bug, but if there are any "rules" which anyone knows regarding these limit values please let me know.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Your request is almost certainly timing our and/or running out of memory - request less data in each call and paginate through the response to get all records

Comment: By increasing the number of likes given for each post, and comparing the user's Facebook ID with each of the returned likes, I can determine that the user likes the post. However, I do not want to make multiple calls for a post with 5,000 likes or some other large number… if the user's FB id does not match one of the IDs in the likes returned then I assume "likes" is "unknown." 
But… I would prefer a different solution to the problem… do you know of a way to simply get, for each post, and indication if the user corresponding to the passed access token likes the post??

Comment: For example, if there were a field "user_likes" for the Post as there is for a Comment within the Post, my problem would have been solved easily with one call to /me/home?….